# Why size reporting for directory is different than other directories? (ls -l command ext4 filesystem ubuntu 15.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In this image when we enter ls -l in terminal the output of  all directories having 4096 bytes size but the Directory Pictures Size is different from others.Why this is Happened.Pictures Directory contains Nothing in it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please post text *as text* (rather than as an image) unless there is a compelling reason to post it as an image.

Comment: Related answers: https://superuser.com/questions/682809/how-much-space-do-directories-consume
https://serverfault.com/questions/99080/folder-size-is-greater-than-4k-on-ext3

Answer (score 6):

Most likely the `Pictures` directory briefly held a large number of files
(or perhaps a number of files with long names),
causing it to grow larger than its initial size. 
Even if you deleted those files,
the directory never shrinks back to its original size.